# Simplest search possible with Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am new to Meteor and trying to add a very simple search feature to the site. I know there are similar questions on SO, but the answers haven't been applicable.

The search bar is in the header. I've subscribed and published a search. But I don't understand what happens after this. How do I send the data from the search bar so that the database is searched. So, what needs to be added to header.js to get the database to searched.

Below is the relevant code.

header.js

```
Template.header.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var query = $(e.target).find('[name=search]').val();

    ***** What should I add here? *****

    Router.go('searchResults');
  }
});
```

search_results.html

```
<template name="searchResults">
  <ul>
    {{#each questions}}
      <li>{{questionItems}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('searchResults', function(searchValue) {
  return Questions.find({
    body: {
      $regex: searchValue
    }
  });
});
```

router.js

```
Router.route('/searchResults', {
  name: 'searchResults',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [Meteor.subscribe('searchResults')];
  }
});
```

Comment: how is your helper for `questions` defined?

Comment: Right now nothing. I added a data function to the router. But it still isn't working. I wonder if something is wrong with the regex search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a route to display the search results you can simply pass the search string to the route. For example:

```
Template.header.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var query = $(e.target).find('[name=search]').val();
    Router.go('/searchResults/'+query);
  }
});
```

Then in your route:

```
Router.route('/searchResults/:searchValue', {
  name: 'searchResults',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [Meteor.subscribe('searchResults',this.params.searchValue)];
  },
  data: function(){
    return Questions.find();
  }
});
```

Your publication is already expecting that query string anyway so you should be good to go!

Comment: have you looked into using a package like easy-search?

Comment: Console outputs this: Uncaught Error: No route found named "searchResults/testsearch".

Comment: I believe `Router.go('searchResults/'+query);` needs to be  `Router.go('/searchResults/'+query);` (with a slash at the beginning)

Comment: Got it. What should go in my searchResults.js ? For the template helpers?

Comment: Fixed the missing forward slash

Comment: @JonRoby: I modified the router code in my answer to include a *data* function that returns the cursor needed by your template. Alternatively you can use a helper to do the `Questions.find()`

Comment: I added the additional code and it routes correctly, but it isn't returning any results. I changed 'body' to 'title' and am sure that there is a title with the word I entered. But still no results are returned. Odd.

Comment: do `Questions.find().count()` from the console and see if you have the right number. If so then the problem is in the template & helper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86943/discussion-between-jon-roby-and-michel-floyd).